# Mongodb not detecting server in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I'm not sure what's going on here. I'm currently hosting a mongodb server that has things in it. However whenever I go to the mongo shell to connect and see what's in there, I don't see anything.

I called `show dbs` and I only see the "local" server.

```
C:\Users\Brent\Dropbox\Muzzler\server\setup>mongod --config mongod.cfg
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.551 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6448 port=21111 dbpath=C:\Users\Brent\Dropbox\Muzzler\server\data 64-bit host=KIR
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.552 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.552 [initandlisten] git version: 52fe0d21959e32a5bdbecdc62057db386e4e029c
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.552 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.552 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.552 [initandlisten] options: { config: "mongod.cfg", dbpath: "C:\Users\Brent\Dropbox\Muzzler\server\data", port: 21111 }
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.554 [initandlisten] journal dir=C:\Users\Brent\Dropbox\Muzzler\server\data\journal
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.554 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.604 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 21111
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.604 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 22111
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.984 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50034 #1 (1 connection now open)
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.984 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50035 #2 (2 connections now open)
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.984 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50036 #3 (3 connections now open)
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.984 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50037 #4 (4 connections now open)
Wed Mar 19 02:28:20.985 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50038 #5 (5 connections now open)
```

How do I know that it's not just empty? I have a website running and reading something from the db, which shows that it has some content.

I think I'm missing something simple here. Please advice.

Comment: How about copying the messages and putting them here properly?

Comment: Didn't think of that. Added as requested.